# Why do people tap the back of cameras during filming?

Tags: film-techniques, film-industry, cinematography

At 58 min 49s, the video above shows on-set footage of a film crew. (Link is setup to start playing from there.)

For a few seconds, it shows people following the camera and repeatedly tapping the back of the camera.

Why are they doing this? Is this still a thing with modern equipment?

Comment: I have never seen anyone do this on set... If I had to guess, it's to add jitter to the frame since the camera's on a Steadicam and they don't want it to look too smooth... they want it to be a little bumpy.

Comment: Too busy LMFAO for an hour and a half... what was the question?

Comment: The scenes they do it in are action scenes after all.

Comment: @Catija Hm, makes sense! Kinda ironic how tech. can get so good some times that people reject it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a method used to add camera shake (as @Catija suggested). The anti-shake features present on the cameras would otherwise make the effect have to be done in post-production, which is far more expensive.